# With the presence of .net reflectors, the encrypting methods become useless?

Tags: vb.net, security, google-cloud-sql, .net-reflector

With the presence of .net reflectors, i see that the encrypting methods become useless because the reflector user will see the way,the key and all info that he wants to decrypt my encrypted data and passwords !!

for my case, i have an application that connects to Google MySql instance, and it's secured by many things : password,SSL connection and certificates.

Now, if i want to give it to my clients, then they can easily disassemble it and see my connection string and passwords and also ssl certificates .... and even if those info are encrypted, the clients (or hackers) will see how i encrypted them and then they can easily decrypt them and hack my database !!!!

What is the secure way to protect any application with the presence of their reflectors ??!!

Thank You.

Comment: You have this rather backwards, it is *thanks* to the decompiler that you could see that your code suffers from a significant security problem.  An attacker doesn't actually need a decompiler.  There is no substitute for physical security, you have to have a lock on the door.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing a lot many things and, as far as I know, if you're embedding connection strings or passwords in your code, you're in the wrong way.

Usually you'll define connection strings in your application configuration file (i.e. `Web.config` or `App.config`), and you should be able to secure this data using [encrypted configuration files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You might also read [this article on MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gaurav/archive/2013/12/16/encrypting-section-of-config-file-using-aspnet-regiis-exe-the-configuration-for-physical-path-web-config-cannot-be-opened.aspx) which will point you in the right direction to encrypt non-web configuration files.

Summary: don't embed sensitive information in code.

Comment: thank you, but i am wondering if these encryption methods are vulnerable or not ?

Comment: @AymAnAbuOmar They're not vulnerable until a hacker has entered to your computer and can execute `aspnet_regiis` to decrypt your configuration file...

Comment: @AymAnAbuOmar But anyway there's no perfect security approach to anything, because as we human can fail in some part, any approach is still vulnerable... This is a principle of encryption science...